# Firebase Database Design : Calendar app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase database (to NoSQL in general). I am designing a app similar to Google calendar. Users can create events and invite other users. Other users can respond to this event by going, not going, maybe going.

This is what I designed (from my MySQL experience):

```
public class User {
   String email;
   String name;
}


public class Event {
    int id;
    String name;
    String topic;
    //other fields
}

public class EventSubscription {
    int id;
    String userEmail;
    String eventId;
    String status
}
```

The user can update the event (add or modify invited users, change any data) or remove the event (which will delete all invites to invited users).

Is this database design good enough?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for commenting. Can we have any other schema which will be better to work with?

Comment: I mispoke, not realizing that Firebase isn't SQL.  Someone who knows Firebase better should instead comment.  In SQL, your schema looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

it can be look like this too

```
public class User {
       String email;
       String name;
       List<HashMap<String ,String>> invitation; // the key is eventId, the value is the status
    }


    public class Event {
        int id;
        String name;
        String topic;
        //other fields
    }
```